# Removing Ubuntu 18.04 motd

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, motd

Anyone know exactly which package(s) to remove to git rid of all the login cruft on Ubuntu 18.04?

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-52-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * MicroK8s 1.15 is out! It has already been installed on more
   than 14 different distros. Guess which ones?

     https://snapcraft.io/microk8s
```

I thought it might be the `update-motd` package but after issuing `apt purge update-motd` there are still files/directories left in `/etc/`.  `dpkg -S` reports these files belong to the `base-files` package which I probably don't want to purge.

```
# find /etc/ | grep motd
/etc/motd
/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/motd-news.timer
/etc/update-motd.d
/etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text
/etc/update-motd.d/97-overlayroot
/etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news
/etc/update-motd.d/00-header
/etc/default/motd-news

# dpkg -S /etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text 
base-files: /etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text
```

I've gotten around this in the past with just brute-force file removal but wondering if there's a better way to do it. Preferably something I could also easily work into an `ansible` playbook.

Comment: per-user and system-wide solutions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/32802/388448

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The motd comes from [here](https://motd.ubuntu.com/). To remove it, open `/etc/default/motd-news` and set `ENABLED=0`.

See this [thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14663947) from Hacker News.